# Was this character the only person in Batman: TAS to discover Batman's secret identity?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, mask-of-the-phantasm

In the Mask of the Phantasm film,

> Andrea Beaumont discovers that Batman is Bruce Wayne when they catch Batman standing near his parents' grave.

Would this make them the first, possibly only, character in Batman: TAS to divine Batman's identity without Batman confiding in them?

Edit: Upon further consideration, excluding the What-If episode and dream sequences.

Comment: I'll have to do some research, but I'm pretty Sure Zatanna figured it out of her own accord, although she knew Bruce Wayne from his days of training with her father, John Zatara as an escape artist. I can't confirm this yet though, so it's just a comment for now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By no means. Across the DC Animated Universe, there are quite a number of people who have figured it out. Broken down by series:

### *Batman: The Animated Series* and *The New Batman Adventures*

- **Ra's al Ghul** figured it out all on his own, as revealed in ["The Demon's Quest"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Demon%27s_Quest). He possibly told Ubu, his manservant, but we can't be certain

  [image]
- **Talia al Ghul** removes Batman's mask in [her first episode](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Off_Balance); although she doesn't confirm that she recognized him, it's doubtful that she didn't. He's Bruce freaking Wayne
- **Hugo Strange**, who figured it out in ["The Strange Secret of Bruce Wayne"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Strange_Secret_of_Bruce_Wayne) by analyzing Bruce's subconscious thoughts

  [image]
- **Kyodai Ken** and **HARDAC**, discussed in [Nu'Daq's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126383/31051). **Randa Duane**, a side character in "Heart of Steel", learned at the same time as HARDAC
- **Tim Drake**, the second Robin (in DCAU continuity) broke into the Batcave in ["Sins of the Father"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Sins_of_the_Father)
- It's likely that **Zatanna** figured it out. In her [eponymous episode](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Zatanna_(episode)) she connects Batman to "John Smith", the name Bruce used when training with her father Zatarra, but it's unknown at that time whether she connects him with Bruce Wayne. It's revealed in *Justice League* (and implied by an episode of *The New Batman Adventures*) that she did eventually learn that they were the same

As well, Bruce's old karate sensei **Yoru** *probably* knew, but this is never confirmed.

### *Superman: The Animated Series*

- **Clark Kent** used his X-Ray vision to peek under the cowl in ["World's Finest"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest)
- **Lois Lane** learns later in "World's Finest" after, of all the stupid things, Batman's cape and cowl get caught in a printing machine and torn off

### *Justice League*

- Presumably **Hawkgirl**, since she shows up uninvited in the Batcave in ["Starcrossed"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Starcrossed)
- It's strongly implied in ["Maid of Honor"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Maid_of_Honor) that **Wonder Woman** figured it out. She and Bruce Wayne dance early in the first part of the episode, and she mentions the event to Batman at the end of the second part. Since Batman claims not to know what she's talking about, we can presume that he didn't tell her

### *Justice League Unlimited*

- It's implied that **Amanda Waller** has figured it out in the episode ["Ultimatum"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimatum). That she knows will later be confirmed in *Batman Beyond*

### *Static Shock*

The main character of the series, **Static**, figures it out when he meets Alfred in the Batcave, and then later sees him with Bruce Wayne

### *Batman Beyond*

- **Terry McGinnis**, the main character of the series, figures it out when he stumbles upon the Batcave
- **Joker** is revealed to have learned from Tim Drake, after extensive torture

Comment: probably the most significant one, I suppose besides Superman, is Amanda Waller: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruwIBT-noAs

Comment: Not to mention Terry McGinnis, who figured it out when he stumbled upon the BatCave after helping old Bruce with his meds.

Comment: And Lois Lane on the first Batman/Superman crossover episode, when his cape gets caught on a printing press which rips off his cowl in front of her.

Comment: @EuroMicelli “his cape gets caught on a printing press which rips off his cowl” — Batman has a plan for everything, *except* the machinations of that crafty old fox Gutenberg.

Comment: Considering how Bruce wasn't surprised of seeing Talia walking in into the batcave in Batman Beyond, I think he knew that she knew.

Answer (score 10):

No- I'll have to do some digging to give you names and episode titles but from TAS I can point out at least three others- Ras Al' Ghul (actually had the balls to confront Bruce in the batcave), a ninja who fought both batman and Bruce Wayne and realized they were the same person because they had the same fighting technique, and the artificial intelligence HARDAC (or something like that) which learned Bruce's identity when batman interfered with its plans to replace all humans with android doubles. There may even be other examples I've overlooked.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten Kyodai Ken and HARDAC

Answer (score 2):

In order: as far as I got on the rewatch) (in order by Wikipedia and may not be in episode order as HBOMAX has it)

Alfred Pennyworth of course new all along.

Robin, Dick (aka Night wing) knew as a child after being taking care of by Bruce Wayne. He was on the search for the killer that murder Dick’s parents and expose himself as Batman.

Bruce Wayne, doctor gave Batman a shot after he was exposed to poison. The blood would surly come back as Bruce Wayne. She came to his machan when Bruce lost his eye sight and said he should take a rest as well as Batman should. (two different episodes)

Out in Crime Alley, Leslie Thompkins (Who helped a young Bruce Wayne cope with the loss of his parents) accompanies Batman to place roses on the spot where his parents were gunned down. Bruce Wayne was well known to do this every year. Leslie would of than known who he was.

The Gray Ghost was told by Batman that he use to watch the show with his dad. He later said the same thing as Batman, in which the grey ghost know knew who Batman was.

Hugo Strange, a psychiatrist. Bruce soon learns that Strange has invented a machine that extracts people's darkest secrets from their minds & transfers them to videotape — & now Strange has proof of Bruce's secret identity as Batman, & plans to auction it to three of Gotham's prominent crime bosses. two-face, Joker and Penguin now learn Bruce Wayne is Batman and dismiss it as well as Jim Gordon also hears that Bruce Wayne is Batman.

a prototype AI known as Holographic Analytical Reciprocating Digital Computer (HARDAC) learns That Bruce Wayne is Batman after Randa Duane had found the batcave. Both were destroy but not after AL created a Bruce Wayne/Batman robot.

While following Count Vertigo's trail, Batman encounters Talia, daughter of the head of the Society of Shadows, who was sent by her father to prevent the capture of a sonic drill that the Count stole. But after his identity is accidentally revealed to Talia, Batman remains off-balance as to where her true loyalties lie.

magician Zatanna finds out Batman is Bruce Wayne when Bruce (as Jhon Smith) had always called her by her name, as Batman did also.

(possible) Thanks to a freak accident during a high-speed chase, the Batmobile is virtually demolished. After Batman takes the car to his personal mechanic, Earl Cooper, the Penguin makes his move & tampers with the Batmobile, putting it under his control. Earl would later learn Batman is Bruce as Batman gave him a new place and said he can by everything from his companies. (Bruce Wayne's companies?)

Catwoman generally discovers that Batman is Bruce Wayne in just about every iteration of their relationship in the comics, animated series, and movies

Barbara was found to be batgirl as Bruce told her he was Batman. In the comics Batman has a relationship with Barbara while she was with Dick which is the reason Dick left to become Night Wing. In Batman Beyond, Barbara speaks to the new Batman (Terry) In which she spoke that her dad knew who she was so it would make since that Jim Gordon knew Bruce Wayne was Batman at the time of Jokers death.

Talia al Ghul removes Batman's mask in her first episode; although she doesn't confirm that she recognized him